# Sum of 2 elements in array - Algorithm - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, function, sum

I'm working on JavaScript algorithms and could use some help. What am I doing wrong exactly?

// Given an array of arr, positive integers, and another number X.

// Determine whether or not there exist two elements in arr whose sum is exactly X.

```
function keyPair(arr, x){
    var sum=false;
    var key=0;
    var temp=0;
    for(var i=0;i<=arr.length;i++){
        while(sum=false){
            key=arr[i];
            arr[i]=temp;
            temp=key;
        }
        if(temp+arr[i]==x){
            sum=true;
        }
    }
    console.log(sum);
}
keyPair([1,2,4,3,6], 4);
```

Comment: `while(sum=false)` is a loop that will never run - you mean `while(sum==false)` or `while(sum===false)`

Comment: Ah interesting. I thought it would work, since if its still false, to keep checking until true. I changed it to == and I got Fatal JavaScript invalid size error 195652814. Is there something else going on, I'm not seeing?

Comment: Note that your `while` loop doesn't change `sun`, so the condition `sum==false` is always true, meaning it's an infinite loop.

Comment: @Orius 1. sum is changed to true inside the while loop, however 2. `(sum=false)` is ALWAYS false

Comment: @Orius Yes, that's correct and you helped me figure out what I was doing wrong. temp is changing because the loop is iterating i. I'm trying to figure out how to use temp to check the true statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think this one deserves an explanation:

`sum=false` is an assignment statement. As an expression, an assignment statement is evaluated as `undefined` (regardless of the value assigned). So `while(sum=false)` is actually `while(undefined)`, which is interpreted as `while(false)`.

Comment: ok so I was declaring sum to equal false. Oops. Thanks for helping me understand this concept

Comment: `while(sum=false)` is actually `while(false)` - because `sum=false` evaluates to `false` (regardless of any other assignations anywhere

Comment: @Bravo Got it, that makes sense, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake was - as explained multiple times - the wrong comparison operator. I took the liberty of rewriting your code involving a `.reduce()` call:

```js
function keyPair(arr,sum){
 return arr.reduce((a,c,j)=>{
  let i=arr.indexOf(sum-c);
  if (i>-1 && j<i) a.push([c,arr[i]]);
  return a;}, []);
}
console.log(keyPair([1,2,4,3,6], 5));
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm not at this stage yet, so I don't know what this is tbh.Even though I corrected my operators, my code still runs in an infinite loop. Do you know why that is?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to repeat what has been already said about your code. But even if you're starting coding in JS, it pays for you to start using JS built-ins that will save you a lot of time:

> // Determine whether or not there exist two elements in arr whose sum is exactly X.

So you're only interested in `whether` they exist, not in which are those:

```js
const keyPair = (arr,value) => 

// some: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

// slice: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

arr.some( (x,i) => arr.slice(i).some( y => x + y === value));


console.log(keyPair([1,2,4,3,6], 4))
console.log(keyPair([1,1,1,1,1], 4))
```

With `some` you check if there is an x+y sum that equals to your desired value

With `slice` you omit the portion of the array that you don't need to check

Answer (score -1):

first off, you might want to start by considering changing while(sum=false) to (sum===false), although running on vs code- it does run regardless.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).